# Heroku Config Variable 32kb limit: Bypasses or alternatives?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, encryption

Over the years I have been storing some `.pem` certs as Heroku's Config variables for Apple push notifications, etc., but I have just hit the [32kb limit](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars#limits). Is there an alternative to Heroku Config variables that I can use to keep server secrets secure?

One possible solution I can think of is storing an encrypted text file on our server, and save the file path and encryption key within the Config vars. But could the dyno properly decrypt during startup? I'm not sure.

Any help/thoughts would be appreciated. Thank you!

FYI, I have Rails+PostgreSQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways you can solve this.
One solution:

You could store S3 credentials in the Heroku app config vars, and the `.pem` files on the S3 bucket those credentials have access to.

Then, at boot time you download those files and store them on disk.
They aren't stored on your GIT repository and you can rotate them easily (just don't forget to restart the app)

Comment: I ended up implementing this. Thanks for your help!